# Is there a way to loop a set of if statements?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

**Goal:**
After the user inputs whether they want to add another new item or not I want the code to start over at the `newItem` input line so that I don't have to just keep the `if`-train going and end up adding a cap to it.

Listed below is the code I've written so far.

```
shopping_cart_menu = [] 
shopping_cart_prices = []

print("Welcome to the shopping cart program. Please select an option from the menu below.")
print("*******************")
print("01: Add a new Item")
print("02: Display Cart contents")
print("03: Remove Item")
print("04: Compute Total")
print("05: Quit")
print("*******************")

menuAnswer = input(" ")

if menuAnswer == "01":
    newItem = input("What item would you like to add? ")
    shopping_cart_menu.append({newItem})
    followUp = input("Would you like to add another item? Y/N: ")
          if answer = "Y"
```

Comment: Look up `while` loops. They let you loop based on the condition. For example to loop until the user inputs `"N"`

Comment: You could use a `while True` loop and break from it when `followUp = 'N'`

Answer (score 1):

Using a while loop will allow you to loop the if statements. The line "followup = followup.upper()" will capitalise the input too.

```
shopping_cart_menu = [] 
shopping_cart_prices = []

print("Welcome to the shopping cart program. Please select an option from the menu below.")
print("*******************")
print("01: Add a new Item")
print("02: Display Cart contents")
print("03: Remove Item")
print("04: Compute Total")
print("05: Quit")
print("*******************")

menuAnswer = input(" ")

if menuAnswer == "01":
    followup = "Y"
    while followup == "Y":
        newItem = input("What item would you like to add? ")
        shopping_cart_menu.append({newItem})
        followup = input("Would you like to add another item? Y/N: ")
        followup = followup.upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use a `while` loop:

```
menuAnswer = input(" ")

if menuAnswer == "01":
    while True:
        newItem = input("What item would you like to add? ")
        shopping_cart_menu.append({newItem})
        followUp = input("Would you like to add another item? Y/N: ")
        if answer != "Y":                          
            break
```